# Validation rule to prevent creating records of certain record type not working

Tags: validation-rule

I have the following validation rule to prevent a certain user from creating Account records of certain recordtype. However it is not working. The user can create records of this record type.

```
AND(
  ISNEW(),
  RecordTypeId = "012Z0000000ZXxXXXXX",
  $User.Alias = "something"
)
```

Comment: never use hardcoded IDs - use `RecordType.DeveloperName = 'Foo'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue might be related to record-type id or User aliasname.

Instead of hardcoding the id's you can use RecordType.DeveloperName = "API name of record type" or RecordType.Name = "Label name of record type".  If you still want to use Recordid try using "RecordType.Id"

[image]

[RecordType documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_recordtype.htm)